# Batch Game - Draw a reference to a name

Tags: batch-file

How do you ask the user for their name, not using %USERNAME% or something, but just asking for their input, then drawing a reference to that later.
This is my core so far

```
echo Who are you?
set /p Name = Enter your name:
set name= %Name% 
echo Hello %name%
pause
goto WakeUp
:WakeUp
```

Comment: Incidentally, your code doesn't work because batch considers spaces to be part of the variable names, so your first variable is actually `Name `. (It's also worth noting that except for the variables set by `for` loops, variable names in batch are case-insensitive so you second set statement is redundant.)

Answer (score 3):

```dos
echo Who are you?
set /p Name=Enter your name : 
echo Hello %name%
pause
:WakeUp
```

Comment: ... and in this case the "goto wakeup" can be eliminated